# Is it possible to get user location and find mobile stores near them?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not familiar with Google maps api , but i am trying to make a simple project i want to get user location via GPS and than show mobile stores near them . I am good at PHP and MYSql .But have no idea about how this can be achieved any help will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

For location, you can either get it from user's ip address, using some kind of [ip to address api](http://ip-api.com/); or use the [HTML Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp), which require some javascript.

With your current location, you can do a [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchRequests) in the Google Maps Places API, which should return you a list of result.

Comment: is there some problem in the nearby search requests link ??